# Pandas groupby().count() function raising error on subset of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I got two dataframes:

```
>>> prodDataframe
       n        bDatum
0      1135     2020-12-09
1      1135     2021-05-12
2      1135     NaT
3      1135     2021-10-31
4      1135     2022-03-25
...    ...      ...
1572   9840123  2021-03-03
1573   9840123  NaT
1574   9840123  2021-11-21
1575   9840123  2022-04-15
1576   9840123  2022-09-09
1577 rows × 2 columns
```

```
>>> stammDataframe
    status  afQuote
n       
1055    0   NaN
1135    1   NaN
1139    1   NaN
1140    1   NaN
1177    1   NaN
... ... ...
9822220 99  NaN
9838523 99  NaN
9838623 99  NaN
9840021 99  NaN
9840123 99  NaN
232 rows × 2 columns
```

I want to fill the `afQuote` column with the amount of entries in the `bDatum` column for each `n` that are not `NaT` , but only for those with a `1` in the `status` column.

Now if I use the whole dataframe it works:

```
stammDataframe.loc[:, 'afQuote'] = stammDataframe.index.map(prodDataframe.groupby('n')['bDatum'].count())
```

However, if I create a subset of the dataframe, I get an error.

```
subDF = stammDataframe.loc[stammDataframe['status'] == 1]
subDF.loc[:, 'afQuote'] = subDF.index.map(prodDataframe.groupby('n')['bDatum'].count())
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[321], line 5
      3 subDF = subDF.iloc[0:4, [1, 24]]
      4 #subDF
----> 5 subDF.loc[:, 'afQuote'] = subDF.index.map(prodDataframe.groupby('n')['bDatum'].count())

File c:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:885, in _LocationIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    882 self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
    884 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 885 iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)

File c:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1893, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1890 # align and set the values
   1891 if take_split_path:
   1892     # We have to operate column-wise
-> 1893     self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
   1894 else:
   1895     self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)

File c:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1937, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(self, indexer, value, name)
   1933     self._setitem_with_indexer_2d_value(indexer, value)
   1935 elif len(ilocs) == 1 and lplane_indexer == len(value) and not is_scalar(pi):
   1936     # We are setting multiple rows in a single column.
-> 1937     self._setitem_single_column(ilocs[0], value, pi)
...
-> 1820     if element._hasna:
   1821         raise LossySetitemError
   1822     return element

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute '_hasna'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: Full error message

Edit: While trying produce shortened dataframes to post here to reproduce, I noticed something I can't understand. I reduced `prodDataframe` to 45 rows and only the two columns that I need from this with `.iloc()`. Same for `stammDataframe` which I reduced to only five rows and two columns. I still got the same error message. Then I saved those reduced dataframes to csv files to post it here, but when I read those csv files in a new jupyter notebook into dataframes, my original code ran without issue.
(This is not the first operation I'm doing on those dataframes, both have >30 columns and I did probably around 50 operations before I reached this point here)

Edit: This is pandas 2.1.1

Edit: Some more testing, I copied only the necessary lines of code that affect the columns that I need here into a new jupyter notebook and ran it on the whole dataframes without issues. I'm at a loss here.

Final edit: Found the/a problem: I added the `afQuote` column initially with `stammDataframe['afQuote'] = np.NaN`. I changed that to `stammDataframe['afQuote'] = pd.Series(dtype = 'Int64')` and now it works. Alternatively `...count().astype('float')` also fixes it.

I have no idea why that didn't give an error in my testing, cause there I used `np.NaN` as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please give us a way to create the dataframe ourselves, so we can test it ourselves

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Can't reproduce with pandas 2.0.1 and the sample data in your question.

Comment: Added the full error message. Ran into weird behavior while trying to produce sample data. See post edit please